# How to apply the pumping lemma to $\{0^m 1^n \mid 2n \leq m \leq 3n, m,n \geq 0 \}$?

Tags: regular-languages, proof-techniques, pumping-lemma

I'm not really sure the how you would go about proving this language isn't regular with the pumping lemma:

$L= \{0^m 1^n | 2n \leq m \leq 3n, m,n \geq 0   \}$

Does this indicate that $S = 2$, so we start by by using a string $\geq 2$?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own, we have litte to
work with. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered. Your question may then be reopened.
Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure that you have not made a mistake in writing $2n \ge m \ge 3n$? If there is no mistake, what can you say about $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Sorry had it backwards,

but it is $2n \leq m \leq 3n$      and $m,n \geq 0$
for $0^m 1^n$

Comment: Take $m$ longer than the pumping length and pump it out of the bounds.

Comment: So let's say we go with n=2, m=4
$000011$
$xyz$ => $ x=00, y=00, z=11$
... now what?

Comment: @echadromani, it's not quite that simple, you don't know the pumping length, so you can't just pick $n=2$, you need to work a little more abstractly. In this case, given pumping length $p$, we can take the string $s=0^{3p}1^{p}$. This is in $L$, and we know that the $y$ section must be all $0$s (as $y$ is within the first $p$ characters). Then we can pump and we get something with too many $0$s (the number of $1$s doesn't change), which contradicts the pumping lemma (were it regular, the new string should still be in the language). Thus $L$ isn't regular.

Comment: @LukeMathieson, Thanks!
You should repost it as the answer

Comment: p.s. wouldnt it be $0^p 1^(3p)$ since $ m \leq 3n$ and the language is $0^m1^n$

Comment: $m$ is at least $2n$ (and at most $3n$ of course), so I've taken $n=p$, so we have $2p \leq m \leq 3p$.

Comment: @echadromani: The proof structure is clearly laid out in the reference question; I don't know why you needed yet another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pumping lemma proofs, we have to remember that only strings *longer* than the pumping length are guaranteed to be "pumpable" (if the language is regular). Unfortunately we don't (typically) know what the pumping length is, so we have to work a little more abstractly than picking a fixed length string.

In this case, given pumping length $p$, we can take the string $s=0^{3p}1^{p}\in L$ (i.e. we choose the string where $n=p$ and $m=3n=3p$). Now if $L$ were regular, we'd be able to divide $s$ up into three parts $s=xyz$ where:

- $|xy|\leq p$
- $|y| > 0$
- $xyz \in L \Leftrightarrow xy^{i}z\in L $ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$

So with our $s$, we know that $y$ must be a string of $0$'s, as $y$ is non-empty and is a subtring of the first $p$ characters.

Then if we pump *up* (never forget that pumping *down* is also a possibility - consider $0^{2p}1^{p}$) we get the string $s'=0^{3p+|y|}1^{p}$. As $|y|>0$, clearly $s' \notin L$, which contradicts the pumping lemma, therefore $L$ cannot be regular.